# Hierarchical Pandas: How to create hierarchical pandas dataframe from columns of two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

The two list are:

```
lst1, lst2 = np.arange(301), 0.333 * np.arange(301)
```

First I created two data frames with 7 columns each from these lists.

```
arr1, arr2 = np.array_split(lst1, 7), np.array_split(lst2, 7)
df1 = DF(arr1).T
df2 = DF(arr2).T
```

Here, df1 and df2 each have 7 columns.

For example, df1 has following columns:

```
col0 = [0, 1, 2, 43]
col1 = [44,45,..,86]
col6 = [259,...,301]
```

data frame df2 also has also 7 columns.
The goal is to keep these 7 columns side to side in a large data frame.

The result should look like this:
Group Group ... Group
Galaxy Diff Galaxy Diff   Galaxy Diff
0
1
2
................................
43

My attempt is this:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

## Break the data
lst1, lst2 = np.arange(301), 0.333 * np.arange(301)
arr1, arr2 = np.array_split(lst1, 7), np.array_split(lst2, 7)


df1 = DF(arr1).T
df2 = DF(arr2).T

# Assign column names
clm = [ 'Group_%d'%i for i in range(len(arr1))]
df1.columns = clm
df2.columns = clm


# Make data type integer
#for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    #df1[i] = df1[i].astype(int)

df1.to_csv('tmp.txt',sep='\t')
df2.to_csv('tmp2.txt',sep='\t')
```

**Problems**
1. The numbers in df1 are floats they should be integers.
2. The numbers in df2 have so much precision, they shoud be %.3f format.
3. `df1[i] = df1[i].astype(int)` command fails.
4. Also, df1 and df2 are two separate data frames, I want to make them a 
   single hierarchical dataframe with 7 columns each have two sub columns (namely, gal and diff) with  corresponding values.

**Some related links**
https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_hierarchical_data.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html
[How to apply hierarchy or multi-index to panda columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151510/how-to-apply-hierarchy-or-multi-index-to-panda-columns)
[apply hierarchy or multi-index to panda columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249212/apply-hierarchy-or-multi-index-to-panda-columns?rq=1) 
[Pandas reset index on series to remove multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624039/pandas-reset-index-on-series-to-remove-multiindex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved how to combine corresponding columns of two dataframes.
Note: All columns should have same length (rows).

The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Author      : Bhishan Poudel, Physics PhD Student, Ohio University
# Date        : Jun 21, 2017 Wed
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

# Pandas setting to display long dataframe in terminal.
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('precision', 3)
NCOLS = 7

# Break the data (Note that 43*7 = 301)
lst1, lst2 = np.arange(301), 0.333 * np.arange(301) # One row with 301 elements
arr1, arr2 = np.array_split(lst1, NCOLS), np.array_split(lst2, NCOLS) # 43*7 matrix

# Make dataframe
df1, df2 = DF(arr1).T, DF(arr2).T
columns = [ 'Galaxy_%d'%i for i in range(7)]
df1.columns, df2.columns = columns, columns

# Combine respective columns and create new df.
for i in range(7):
    df1.insert(i*2+1,'Diff_%d'%i,df2['Galaxy_%d'%i])

# Multi index from arrays
arr_idx = [ ['Group', '']*7, [ 'Galaxy', 'Diff' ]*7 ] # Double line top index
index   = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arr_idx, names=['', '']) # leftmost index
df1.columns=index
print(df1)

# Write df1 into a file
df1.to_csv('tmp.txt',float_format='%.3f',sep='\t')
```

Here, the terminal prints nice and beautifully formatted dafaframe.

```
    Group          Group          Group          Group          Group          Group          Group        
   Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff Galaxy    Diff
0       0   0.000     43  14.319     86  28.638    129  42.957    172  57.276    215  71.595    258  85.914
1       1   0.333     44  14.652     87  28.971    130  43.290    173  57.609    216  71.928    259  86.247
2       2   0.666     45  14.985     88  29.304    131  43.623    174  57.942    217  72.261    260  86.580
3       3   0.999     46  15.318     89  29.637    132  43.956    175  58.275    218  72.594    261  86.913
4       4   1.332     47  15.651     90  29.970    133  44.289    176  58.608    219  72.927    262  87.246
5       5   1.665     48  15.984     91  30.303    134  44.622    177  58.941    220  73.260    263  87.579
6       6   1.998     49  16.317     92  30.636    135  44.955    178  59.274    221  73.593    264  87.912
7       7   2.331     50  16.650     93  30.969    136  45.288    179  59.607    222  73.926    265  88.245
8       8   2.664     51  16.983     94  31.302    137  45.621    180  59.940    223  74.259    266  88.578
9       9   2.997     52  17.316     95  31.635    138  45.954    181  60.273    224  74.592    267  88.911
10     10   3.330     53  17.649     96  31.968    139  46.287    182  60.606    225  74.925    268  89.244
11     11   3.663     54  17.982     97  32.301    140  46.620    183  60.939    226  75.258    269  89.577
12     12   3.996     55  18.315     98  32.634    141  46.953    184  61.272    227  75.591    270  89.910
13     13   4.329     56  18.648     99  32.967    142  47.286    185  61.605    228  75.924    271  90.243
14     14   4.662     57  18.981    100  33.300    143  47.619    186  61.938    229  76.257    272  90.576
15     15   4.995     58  19.314    101  33.633    144  47.952    187  62.271    230  76.590    273  90.909
16     16   5.328     59  19.647    102  33.966    145  48.285    188  62.604    231  76.923    274  91.242
17     17   5.661     60  19.980    103  34.299    146  48.618    189  62.937    232  77.256    275  91.575
18     18   5.994     61  20.313    104  34.632    147  48.951    190  63.270    233  77.589    276  91.908
19     19   6.327     62  20.646    105  34.965    148  49.284    191  63.603    234  77.922    277  92.241
20     20   6.660     63  20.979    106  35.298    149  49.617    192  63.936    235  78.255    278  92.574
21     21   6.993     64  21.312    107  35.631    150  49.950    193  64.269    236  78.588    279  92.907
22     22   7.326     65  21.645    108  35.964    151  50.283    194  64.602    237  78.921    280  93.240
23     23   7.659     66  21.978    109  36.297    152  50.616    195  64.935    238  79.254    281  93.573
24     24   7.992     67  22.311    110  36.630    153  50.949    196  65.268    239  79.587    282  93.906
25     25   8.325     68  22.644    111  36.963    154  51.282    197  65.601    240  79.920    283  94.239
26     26   8.658     69  22.977    112  37.296    155  51.615    198  65.934    241  80.253    284  94.572
27     27   8.991     70  23.310    113  37.629    156  51.948    199  66.267    242  80.586    285  94.905
28     28   9.324     71  23.643    114  37.962    157  52.281    200  66.600    243  80.919    286  95.238
29     29   9.657     72  23.976    115  38.295    158  52.614    201  66.933    244  81.252    287  95.571
30     30   9.990     73  24.309    116  38.628    159  52.947    202  67.266    245  81.585    288  95.904
31     31  10.323     74  24.642    117  38.961    160  53.280    203  67.599    246  81.918    289  96.237
32     32  10.656     75  24.975    118  39.294    161  53.613    204  67.932    247  82.251    290  96.570
33     33  10.989     76  25.308    119  39.627    162  53.946    205  68.265    248  82.584    291  96.903
34     34  11.322     77  25.641    120  39.960    163  54.279    206  68.598    249  82.917    292  97.236
35     35  11.655     78  25.974    121  40.293    164  54.612    207  68.931    250  83.250    293  97.569
36     36  11.988     79  26.307    122  40.626    165  54.945    208  69.264    251  83.583    294  97.902
37     37  12.321     80  26.640    123  40.959    166  55.278    209  69.597    252  83.916    295  98.235
38     38  12.654     81  26.973    124  41.292    167  55.611    210  69.930    253  84.249    296  98.568
39     39  12.987     82  27.306    125  41.625    168  55.944    211  70.263    254  84.582    297  98.901
40     40  13.320     83  27.639    126  41.958    169  56.277    212  70.596    255  84.915    298  99.234
41     41  13.653     84  27.972    127  42.291    170  56.610    213  70.929    256  85.248    299  99.567
42     42  13.986     85  28.305    128  42.624    171  56.943    214  71.262    257  85.581    300  99.900
```